# How to Export a REPO in SUSE Sles15

Tags: opensuse, repo, suse

I have a repo on my Virtualbox VM "uyuni-server-stable" that i need to export to USB.
The other VM has no Internet connection and the REPO needs to be first imported and then added.

How can i export this repo?
[image: My Repos]

Comment: Just curious, Is the specific repository resides on some server in Local Network?
To backup all repositories
Have you tried `sudo zypper lr --export <filename.repo>` e.g. `sudo zypper lr --export example.repo` for exporting and then `sudo zypper ar example.repo` to import it.